# Using Google+ Hangouts API

Tags: php, chat, bots, google-hangouts

If someone adds bot@mydomain.com to his Google Hangout contacts and sends it a Google+ Hangout Chat message, I want to set up an automatic reply to his chat from my server. Is there a way to do that??

I think Its possible using the Google+ Hangouts API but I cannot figure out how.

(mydomain.com uses Google Apps for Business)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you're looking:
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data

Here's the event for message recieved: (callback) https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.onMessageReceived

And here's the event for sending the message:
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.sendMessage

Comment: Isn't this only for Hangouts created using a Google+ Hangout Button on your own website? I want to make something like a bot. Like whenever a msg is received from any hangout to my bots account,it replies back with a specific message.

Comment: @kakashihatake2 this would be a G+ app, so a user would have to add and accept your app, otherwise yeah you'd need to write a custom Jabber api.

Comment: Ummmm.... But how will I make the Google Hangout remember this forever, How will I make my user communicate with only and only my bot? Lets say he uses Google Hangout from his phone, then how will he communicate with my bot?

Comment: So this document is about your app's running state @ https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/running.  Essentially your app would be a JS application, from JS you can pass data between the browser and your server side end.  However, I think you're really looking for a Jabber hack here, i.e. if you plan on setting up a new google account so you can literally see a client, then yeah you want to go the custom Jabber route (aka connect google's chat server).

Comment: Hangouts doesn't support XMPP/Jabber. Talk did, but Hangouts doesn't.

Comment: @JopVernooij that's correct, thanks for pointing that out.  Hangouts doesn't support xmpp/jabber, I don't think it even supports Websocket.  However, my answer above is still correct as it corresponds with the official documentation provided by Google.

Comment: @JopV. correction - it does, but you have to enable "insecure apps" on your google account. I'm using Pidgin with Hangouts through XMPP right now.