# Google api: hangout send and get chat messages

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Ok, so I'm trying to make like a minigame bot for me and my friends to play like text based games in google hangouts, but i really don't understand how the hangouts api works?

Can you make a chrome app that sends messages to a group chat and if so how? I have checked out the google dev api page but it seems like it explains how to do stuff with videochats, not "regular chat".

I have checked out: [Using Google+ Hangouts API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302394/using-google-hangouts-api) but i don't know where i should use that code.

And i want it to be for just hangouts chat, not like the videochatting chat